# Unit test fails when BroadcastReceiver sends an Intent to an IntentService

Tags: android, unit-testing, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have an `BroadcastReceiver` that starts an `IntentService`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ParamsRequest paramsRequest = new ParamsRequest.Builder()
            .setUrl(intent.getStringExtra("url"))
            .build();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("paramsKey", paramsRequest);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

And `MyIntentService` retrieves the `Intent` (with the object `paramsRequest`):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    ParamsRequest paramsRequest = (ParamsRequest) intent.getSerializableExtra("paramsKey");

    //more code
}
```

I have a test to ensure that the intent is sent and retrieved correctly:

```
@Test
public void testStartAndroidProofService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AndroidProofService.class);
    intent.putExtra("paramsKey", paramsRequest);

    receiver.onReceive(context, intent);
    assertNull(receiver.getResultData());

    ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argumentIntent = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
    Mockito.verify(context, times(1)).startService(argumentIntent.capture());
    assertEquals(paramsRequest, argumentIntent.getValue().getSerializableExtra("paramsKey"));
}
```

But the `AssertEquals` fails:

[image]

Any idea why I'm having 2 different objects?

**EDIT:** The `Intent` captured in `argumentIntent.capture()` contains a `ParamsRequest` object but all the fields in this object are `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what was going on. The root of the problem was that the flow I had in my mind about the process was wrong:

1. Build an `Intent` and set `ParamsRequest` as an extra
2. Pass this `Intent` to `BroadcastReceiver` through `onReceive()`
3. `onReceive()` performs operations with the data into the`Intent`
4. Call `startService()` with the above `Intent`

The issues found in the above logic:

- I'm setting `ParamsRequest` object as an extra in the `Intent` retrieved in the `onReceive()`. That's wrong because the `ParamsRequest` object has to be built **inside** the `onReceive()`.
- I'm comparing the `Intent` retrieved in the `onReceive(Context, Intent)` with the `Intent` sent in the `startService(Intent)` as if they were the same `Intent`. That is wrong because they are different `Intents` since the second `Intent`, which is used in the `startService(Intent)`, is built from the data contained in the first `Intent`.

So the fixed test is:

```
@Test
public void testStartService() {
    // I build the Intent that the onReceive() will receive
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("url", "https://fakeurl.com");

    //I simulate that the BroadcastReceiver is triggered, calling the onReceive() method and passing the above Intent
    receiver.onReceive(context, intent);

    //The actual code inside onReceive() instantiates a new Intent and calls startService(Intent)

    // I capture the new Intent instantiated inside the onReceive() method
    ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argumentIntent = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
    Mockito.verify(context, times(1)).startService(argumentIntent.capture());

    //I retrieve the url from the ParamsRequest object setted in the captured Intent        
    ParamsRequest paramsRequest = (ParamsRequest) argumentIntent.getValue().getSerializableExtra("paramsRequest_key");
    String url = paramsRequest.getUrl();
    assertEquals("https://fakeurl.com", url);
}
```

And the test passes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It's about serialization.

When you put `ParamsRequest` into `Intent`, underneath the hood, all fields in the `ParamsRequest` are converted into string, boolean, int, etc so they can be stored. Later when you retrieve  `ParamsRequest` from `Intent`, all those values are collected and a new `ParamsRequest` are created. Therefore, the initial `ParamsRequest` and the second `ParamsRequest` are different objects and then you get an assertion error.

What you want to do here is compare every field or `ParamsRequest` or override `equals` of `ParamsRequest`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Makes sense what you say, so now I'm comparing the fields of the object and I realize that the retrieved object has all the fields to `null`, so something is wrong in my test.